# While rendering, after a few seconds my screen glitches out, then my computer BSOD's

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

My PC is custom built, it has a Ryzen 5 1600 14nm and an AMD rx 570 with 16 GB of ram on a gigabyte b450m ds3h motherboard. Nothing is overclocked and I can run games just fine and with blender it seems to have the same power draw so I don't think its a power issue. In games, I have not experienced anything like this, even with max power draw. https://youtu.be/B6w_vKzFH6Q that is a video of the issue. I have tried limiting the power draw of my GPU and that doesn't help. My drivers are up to date, I'm using open cl with my CPU and GPU checked and under cycles settings, I have my GPU as my compute device. Even if I render with CPU as my device, it still happens. Didn't used to happen. Temperatures are just fine usually around 60-70 while under load.

This is a link to the project I am trying to render https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pgYE_1C1TcLQLkrghEq8Nac6qNlHIWAD?usp=sharing
the images were rendered on a different computer.

Comment: Screen/ graphical issues are almost always gpu problems rather than blender ones. Please [revise](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/191694/edit) your question to include information about the scene you are rendering. Start blender from command line with `--debug-all --factory-startup` flags and see if issue persists.

Comment: It's your graphics card for sure. I suggest install the latest drivers and if that doesn't help for whatever reason, please file a bug report. Help > Report a Bug

Answer (score 1):

I have found that when I have instant replay on and record desktop on in radeon settings, it crashes. If turned off, I have no issues at all. Thank you for your time.